# complete semilattice and its not subsemilattice/a counter-example

Tags: lattice-orders

Is there an example of a complete semi-lattice and its subset which is itself a complete semi-lattice without being sub-semi-lattice of the bigger one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be the semi-lattice in the picture below:

[image]

Now, let $A=\{2,3,18\}$. It is still a semi-lattice, but not a sub-semi-lattice of $S$, since $2 \vee 3 =12$ in $S$.

Code (this editor seems not adequate for this, but here it goes):
`\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add,pst-node}`
`\begin{pspicture}(3,2)`
`\psset{unit=.75cm}`
`\psset{radius=0.1,labelsep=.1}`
`\Cnode(0,0){2}     \nput{180}{2}{$2$}`
`\Cnode(2,0){3}     \nput{0}{3}{$3$}`
`\Cnode(1,1){12}    \nput{30}{12}{$12$}`
`\Cnode(1,2){18}    \nput{90}{18}{$18$}`
`\ncline{12}{2}`
`\ncline{12}{3}`
`\ncline{12}{18}`
`\end{pspicture}`

---

Here's another example in which $A$ is still a sub-semi-lattice of $S$, but not a complete one.
In fact, in this example $S$ is a lattice and $A$ is a sub-lattice, but it works just the same.

Let $S = \wp_{fin}(\mathbb N) \cup \{\mathbb N, \mathbb Q\}$, where $\wp_{fin}(X)$ denotes the family of finite subsets of $X$.
Now, let $A = S \setminus \{\mathbb N\} = \wp_{fin}(\mathbb N) \cup \{\mathbb Q\}$.
Then $A$ is still a sub-lattice (whence a sub-semi-lattice) of $S$, but not a complete one, since $\bigvee \wp_{fin}(\mathbb N) = \mathbb N$, in $S$ but the result is $\mathbb Q$ in $A$.

Comment: OK. Can you have a look at my last comment yet ?

Comment: I'll edit, if you like, to include an example in which $A$ is a sub-semi-lattice of $S$ but not a complete one. Would that be what you want?

Comment: Yes. BTW, what is the code you used for the picture ? Also, there is a unique definite  inequality for the $\sup$'s in the two $L'\subset L$,correct ?

Comment: The picture cam from an exercise in which it was supposed to be the poset $\{2,3,12,18\}$ with division relation. Of course it is wrong, since $12$ is not a divisor of $18$, but it still works here (even with strange labelling). The code is PSTricks. I'll add it too.

Comment: My other question was if this holds in general $$\sup_L X \leq \sup_{L'} X$$ for $X\subseteq L'$ and $L'\subseteq L$?

Comment: Yes, if $\bigvee_{L'} X$ still exists in $L' \subset L$, then $\bigvee_L X \leq \bigvee_{L'}$, but the definition of supremum.